# How can access vistors to the wordpress admin area

Tags: wordpress

I want to access my visitors to the admin area to test my theme before purchase. is there any way to do it?

Just like "wpbakery visual composer" https://vc.wpbakery.com/try/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can give him/her the role of `subscriber` and give him/her username and password.

Comment: It won't help me, Visitors may want to change the theme and see their modifications online! massive dynamic has this feature already: http://demo2.massivedynamic.co/test-drive?testdrive=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a plugin that creates a test drive sandbox for you.

http://codecanyon.net/item/test-drive-sandbox/13970142